# How to handle temporary query results in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I'll describe shortly. 
There is a column `DestinationId`
 and a column `HierarchyNodeId`
Currently there are multiple HierarchyNodeIds for one DestinationId.
I have a query that gives me each DestinationId and the HierarchyNodeId that I want to keep.
So I want to replace every other HierarchyNodeId Associated with each DestinationId with the one I got from the query above.

1. I create a Loop through the query. So each loop cycle I have a certain DestinationId (cursor."DestinationId" and a certain cursor."HierarchyNodeId")
2. I have 3 tables that contain the column "HierarchyNodeId" and I want to update all 3 of them.
3. In each loop cycle I have a query that finds all the HierarchyNodeIds associate with cursor."DestinationId" (current cycle DestinationId)

My problem is the query in step 3 gets data from the 2 out of 3 tables that I want to Update.
So If I use it in my updates 
(example

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1."HierarchyNodeId"=cursor."HierarchyNodeId"
WHERE table1."HierarchyNodeId" IN (queryfromstep3)
```

)
Then I will have a problem since the results from queryfromstep3 will change when I do my first UPDATE.

So I was thinking of Storing the results of queryfromstep3 into a TEMP table at the beginning of each loop.

Is this possible in PL/SQL? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Here is the query I want to store into a TEMP

```
SELECT "HierarchyNodeId" FROM 
(
Select t1."Counter", t2.* From
           (SELECT "HierarchyNodeId", (SELECT "Description"
            FROM "Destination"
           WHERE "DestinationId" = hn."DestinationId") "Description", "DestinationId",
         (SELECT "DestinationTypeId"
            FROM "Destination"
           WHERE "DestinationId" = hn."DestinationId") "DestinationTypeId"
    FROM "HierarchyNode" hn
WHERE "DestinationId" IN (SELECT "DestinationId" From(SELECT COUNT ("HierarchyNodeId"), "DestinationId" FROM "HierarchyNode" GROUP BY "DestinationId" HAVING COUNT ("HierarchyNodeId") > 1))) t2, 
(select COUNT (*) "Counter", "HierarchyNodeId" From "HierarchyDetail"
Group By "HierarchyNodeId") t1
Where t1."HierarchyNodeId" = t2."HierarchyNodeId"
AND t2."DestinationId" = cur."DestinationId"
AND t2."HierarchyNodeId" != cur."HierarchyNodeId"
ORDER BY "DestinationId", "Counter" Desc
)
```

It basically produces 1 column with Guids.
But some of those Guids will change after I do my first UPDATE. In order to avoid that I want to store it into a TEMP table at the beginning of each loop.

Comment: Can you give us some data sample and the rsults you want?

Comment: @A.B.Cade I will add the query but there's no need to make the question heavier by proving more data. I just wanted to know if it's possible to store the results of a Select query into a TEMP table. And then delete that temp table and start over (each time the loop recycles)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Exactly! :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Wait what? You asked me if this is a procedure and I said yes. I am creating a procedure thats why I use pl/sql.
Which is the language used to create Oracle Procedures... But feel free to retag it if you feel it shouldn't be so...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the Oracle Global Temp Table: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables003.htm#ADMIN11633

Comment: This seems to be the way to go with TEMP tables. Thanks.